# Prometheus /Grafana counter sum

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am trying to get the count of kafka message processed over a period by my application the application pushes a counter metrics to Prometheus and produce this

```
{ function_name="input_message" ,instance="" ,job="pushgateway" , processed_count="4"  ,topic="testtopic"} value    4
{ function_name="input_message" ,instance="" ,job="pushgateway" , processed_count="5"  ,topic="testtopic"} value    5
{ function_name="input_message" ,instance="" ,job="pushgateway" , processed_count="6"  ,topic="testtopic"} value    6
```

on Grafana I tried this query the metrics to sum the labels but it didn't produce the desired output, I am looking for a total of processed_count total

```
sum by (function_name,job,processed_count) (rate(update_api_call_count_total { function_name="input_message",job="pushgateway" }[1h]))
```

Comment: Why do you sum by processed_count ? You don't want to only sum identical processed_count right ?

Comment: let say I want to see total messages came to a topic in an hour, I can sum it up and show right?

Comment: Is processed_count always equal to the value of the counter ?